# Производительность OpenGL | C++

Tags: c++, opengl

Я разрабатываю приложение с графическим интерфейсом на OpenGL, я не использую никаких библиотек.
Так как я не сильно знаком с новыми стандартами OpenGL - хотел бы это исправить.

Я знаю что существуют VBO и VAO, и мне стало интересно.
Можно ли отрисовать всю сцену с одним VBO и одним вызовом glDrawArrays?

Если вы знаете какие-то хорошие примеры, или уроки где легко понять как работает Vertex Buffer Object и Vertex Attribute Object, буду благодарен за ссылку.

Comment: Для двухмерной игры - да, на одном VBO все прекрасно работает. Его можно постепенно заполнять данными, отрисовывать когда место заканчивается, и начинать заполнять заново.

Answer (score 2):

Отрисовать 1 vbo можно. Но только скорее всего Ваша сцена будет статичной (хотя можно шейдерами добавить движения).

Хорошие сайты

- https://learnopengl.com/
- перевод на хабре https://habr.com/ru/post/353956/ (ссылка с середины, потому что там более полное содержание)
- http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/
- https://open.gl/
- ну и конечно https://www.khronos.org/opengl/

рекомендую просто прочитать в каждом туториале интересующую Вас тему. Я заметил, что разные темы по разном мне понятны в разных туториалах.